# How to use book_outlined icon in flutter?

Tags: flutter, icons, material-design

I want to use 'book_outlined' icon in flutter, but it does not show up in my app.

book_outlined: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Icons/book_outlined-constant.html

I tried in two way, but always got an error.

```
// 1
Icon(Icons.book_outlined)

//2
Icon(IconData(0xe08f, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons'))
```

```
The getter 'book_outlined' isn't defined for the type 'Icons'.
Try importing the library that defines 'book_outlined', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'book_outlined'
```

Are there any mistake of my code.
Could you give me any advice, please?

Comment: It might be a flutter version problem and that icon maybe a new one. What's the version of your flutter?

Comment: I think my version is 1.17.1 
flutter --version
Flutter 1.17.1

Comment: Yea i think updating it to the latest version will solved the problem. But think about it there's so many deprecated methods, widgets, etc, it might caused some errors on your project.

Comment: OK, I got it. Thank you for your advice!

Answer (score 2):

If updating your Flutter version didn't help then you can switch to master channel. I just checked and the above icon is available there. To switch the channel simply type the command : `flutter channel master`

Comment: switching to master channel and pulling the latest changes worked for me.